# Display SVG favicon for PDF files

Tags: html, pdf, svg, favicon

Before someone closes this because of mistakenly thinking it is a duplicated question, I'm referring to SVG favicon in particular instead of ICO format. And there is a reason for that.

I'm using an SVG favicon in order to support both light and dark modes. In other words, the icon will change colors automatically thanks to the `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` query in the SVG file. I also have a `favicon.ico` placed in the root folder for fallback support (a.k.a. Safari mainly).

Yet, when I open a PDF in a new tab, `favicon.svg` will not be loaded instead, the `favicon.ico` is loaded regardless of whether the browser supports SVG favicon. That can be a problem because the two icons will look different in dark mode, where the SVG icon changes colors while the ICO doesn't.

So is there any way to make the browsers display the "correct" icon?

Comment: Your Browser doesn't (try to) display the icon, its the PDF viewer.

Answer (score 0):

A picture paints a thousand icons

The browser will use favicon.ico or similar for the html content see the left 3 are coloured. However once an embedded frame has full focus it is the pdf viewers task to display any suited icon Here the blob and remote pdf and local pdf do not themselves have a favicon to fall back on.

[image]

Each browser pdf extension will be different but generally it is the browser that provides fall back. Lets use an example svg icon
[image]

Lets Icon nab it and apply it to another site

[image]

now lets try to display that in the iframe only

[image]

Clearly no problems in using SVG ico with PDF until you open in another tab
[image]

I think you are missing the rule that if there is nothing to display in the current html context then the common FALLBACK is addressRoot/favicon.ico so the browser will use that whatever the browser tab color light or dark. so design your ico to match the svg one. However once the addressRoot/ is clients device there is no favicon.ico other than built into the browser, it really has nothing to do with PDF viewer just that is where its more noticable.

[image]

Comment: And how does that answer my question? I already know `favicon.ico` will be used by most browsers, but my question is not related to that.

Comment: So the short answer is "no". I can't control what icons are displayed when the browser's default PDF viewer is displaying PDFs unless I embed the icon inside the PDF. Is that what you are trying to suggests

Comment: Just to make things easier, since I don't need/want to know about how PDFs are handled under the hood. (1) Is it possible to "instruct" the browser/PDF viewer to display a specific favicon (e.g. SVG icon for my case) for ONLINE PDF files, as opposed to `favicon.ico`? (2) If yes, how?

Comment: @MatthewKwong.  Your response to K J seems quite aggressive!  He is simply trying to explain why you are getting the result that you are getting.  You may not be interested in knowing how it works behind the scenes (he was not to know that), but many others reading this question/answer will be.  That is one of the primary reasons why these questions are posted here - to help everyone.  If he had just said 'no', how would that have helped anyone?

Comment: Please try to respect everyone's answers.  People take time out of their busy days to help others all the time.  Their answer may not be the one that we are looking for, but the person has tried to help and has made an effort on your behalf.